# How to take $\int^1_{-1} \frac{xdx}{x^2+x+1}$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Here's the integral:

$$\int^1_{-1} \frac{xdx}{x^2+x+1}$$

So I am basicly confused about $xdx$ if it were only $dx$ I would just compleate the square and go ahead with table formula, but as i can judge it doesn't work properly witx $xdx$

Can someone give me a hint, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I = \int^1_{-1} \frac{x}{x^2+x+1} dx$

$2I = \int^1_{-1} \frac{2x + 1 - 1}{x^2+x+1} dx$

$2I = [\ln|x^{2}+x+1|]_{-1}^{1} -\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2}+x+1}dx$

$2I = \ln3 -\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^{2}+\frac{3}{4}}dx$

Can you solve it from there?

Edit: In case you get stuck:

Let $x+\frac{1}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tan u$

$\Rightarrow dx = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sec^{2}u$

Lower limit:

$-1+\frac{1}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tan u\Rightarrow \tan u = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \Rightarrow u = -\frac{\pi}{3}$

Upper limit:

$\frac{3}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tan u \Rightarrow u = \frac{\pi}{6}$

$2I = \ln3 - \int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}(\tan^{2}u+1)} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sec^{2}u\ du = \ln3 - \int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\ du$

$2I = \ln 3 - (\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}} +\frac{2\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}) = \ln 3 -\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$

$I = \frac{1}{2}(\ln 3 - \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}})$

Comment: One minor question. How did you get  $2x+1-1$ numerator? The rest is totally clear.

Comment: Basically you multiply $I$ by $2$, which gives you $2x$ in the numerator, then we add 1 and subtract 1, so that the first part of the numerator, is the derivative of the denominator (and then we can integrate it), whilst the second part is of the standard form. If you're wondering why I did it, it's because it's a common trick when the highest power of $x$ in the numerator is $1$ less than the highest power of $x$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 3):

Two useful lemma for partial fraction decomposition: let the rational function $p/q$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials in one variable and the degree of $p$ is less than the degree of $q$ (otherwise divide $p$ by $q$ to obtain $s/q$ with the required conditions).

Suppose that the degree of $q$ is $n$, then we can decompose the rational function $p/q$ in simple fractions, that is exists some $a_{j,k}\in\Bbb C$ such that

$$\frac{p}q=\sum_{j=1}^{h}\sum_{k=1}^{m_j}\frac{a_{j,k}}{(x-r_j)^k}\tag{1}$$

where $r_j$ are the roots of $q$ and $m_j$ is it corresponding multiplicity. And where we have that

$$m_1+m_2+\ldots+m_h=n$$

**Lemma 1:** if the roots $r_j$ of $q$ are simple, that is if $m_j=1$ for all $j$, then we can find

$$a_j=\frac{p(r_j)}{q'(r_j)},\quad a_j\in\Bbb C$$

where $q'$ is the derivative of $q$. Then $(1)$ have the simple form

$$\frac{p}q=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_j}{x-r_j}\tag{2}$$

**Lemma 2:** if the coefficients of the polynomials $p$ and $q$ are real then we have that

- if $r_j$ is a real root then all $a_{j,k}$ are real.
- if $r_j$ is complex then $a_{j,k}$ is also complex and exists some root of the same multiplicity $r_h=\bar r_j$ with $a_{h,k}=\bar a_{j,k}$ for each $k$.

---

From the two lemmas together, after a bit of algebra, [we found that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2177051/173262) we can express the integral of the question as a logarithm more an arc-tangent, that is

$$\frac{x}{x^2+x+1}=\frac12\cdot\frac{2x+1-1}{x^2+x+1}=\frac12\left(\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}-\frac1{x^2+x+1}\right)=\\=\frac12\left(\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}-\frac1{(x+1/2)^2+3/4}\right)=\frac12\left(\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}-\frac43\cdot\frac1{\left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt 3}\right)^2+1}\right)=\\=\frac12\left(\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}-\frac2{\sqrt 3}\cdot\frac{2/\sqrt3}{\left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt 3}\right)^2+1}\right)$$

Hence

$$\int\frac{x\mathrm dx}{x^2+x+1}=\frac12\ln(x^2+x+1)-\frac1{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt 3}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

***Hint:***

Complete the square on the denominator and use $u$-substitution, (place your pointer on the rectangle to see hint)

> $$x^2+x+1 = (x+\frac 12)^2+\frac 34$$
>  Then let $u=x+\frac 12$ such that $du = dx$ and $x=u-\frac 12$ to get two integrands in terms of $u$ namely, $$\int \frac u{u^2+\frac 34} - \frac 1{2(u^2+\frac 34)}\;dx$$

switch bounds of integrations into $u$-terms and then use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PartialFractions.aspx)